# Dining philosophers using the resource hierarchy solution

Tags: process, operating-system, resources, dining-philosopher

So the problem with this solution, as I've understood it, is that it's too time consuming. In the [explanation I was reading](http://adit.io/posts/2013-05-11-The-Dining-Philosophers-Problem-With-Ron-Swanson.html) and also on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem#Resource_hierarchy_solution) it's assumed that philosopher #1 has both forks #3 and #5. But now he also needs fork #2, so he drops #3 and #5 then picks up #2, #3 and #5 respectively. Now, in the frame of our example why would a philosopher actually ever need three forks at the same time if he only needs 2 to eat? Or have I misunderstood something along the way?

Comment: Where in either of those texts does it suggest that a philosopher needs three forks?

Comment: "For example, if a unit of work holds resources 3 and 5 and then determines it needs resource 2, it must release 5, then 3 before acquiring 2, and then it must re-acquire 3 and 5 in that order." I thought that's what was implied by this here.

Comment: "Cool, resource hierarchy avoids deadlocks! But it is slow. Suppose you have forks #3 and #5. Then you decide you need fork #2. Well forks #3 and #5 are larger numbers. So you’ll have to:
put down fork #5
put down fork #3 (the order you put these down in doesn’t matter)
pick up fork #2
pick up fork #3
pick up fork #5"

Comment: In the last quote he picks up forks #2, #3 and #5 without dropping anything. So I assumed he now has three forks in his possession.

Comment: The Wikipedia article refers to resources rather than forks, so I think it's safe to assume they are not referring to the dining philosophers example (rather to other scenarios such as databases). The adit.io article does seemingly mention three forks but this seems like a poor choice of wording because in the dining philosophers scenario a philosopher only ever needs two forks to eat. Again, I think they are suggesting that bigger problems need more sophisticated solutions, and they have used the word "forks" when "resources" would have been a better choice.

Comment: As for your initial assessment, I think this sentence from Wikipedia agrees: "Computer programs that access large numbers of database records would not run efficiently if they were required to release all higher-numbered records before accessing a new record, making the method impractical for that purpose." For larger problems the resource hierarchy solution becomes inefficient.